# Clicking a radio button in Selenium with Java for Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

My code runs perfectly on FF and Chrome, the IE driver starts but the radio button is not clicked:

```
    WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='5'][@name='rPay']/following-sibling::span"));
    System.out.println(radio.isDisplayed());
    radio.click();
    System.out.println(radio.isSelected());
```

The output I get is true, false, meaning that the element was visible but not clicked.
Here is the html code I am running my test on:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="CheckPayment(document.frmWS,'');" value="5"    name="rPay" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
<span class="custom-radio"></span>
```

I actually have to click on the span tag, not on the input tag. In Firefox and Chorme it won't work the other way around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching for the whol afternoon I found what was missing. My code for the IE web driver was this:

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, true);
    cap.internetExplorer().setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    cap.setCapability("IE.binary", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe");
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    cap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
    cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\webdriver\\iedriverserver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

After adding one line, I found somewhere on the web, it worked fine:

```
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
```

Thanks a lot for everybodies help anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Please include below capabilities before you call IEDriver.

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);    
ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

*isDisplayed()* and *isSelected()* is what making this difference. 
Lets try below and it should work.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.xpath("//input[@name='rPay']//span[@class='custom-radio']")));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tied to add a wait before and hoave now tried again with your code. Still does not click the radio button. The isDisplayed() is just to assure that the element is present. The isSelected() to check if it worked.

Comment: elementToBeSelected returns a boolean, so I have added my original line: WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='5'][@name='rPay']/following-sibling::span")); and just your line starting with wait... No I get an error message: Timeout waiting for Element to be selected

Comment: like this it works neither on IE nor on the other browsers

Comment: no, it's on a internal server, there is no public access

Comment: Is it possible that the very same xpath expression works for Firefox and Chrome but not for IE?

Comment: Not its not about xpath or the check-box , the problem lies in the IE how it renders the Web-Elements. here are some links i have come across.  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4403      https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2857  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8302

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :-

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='5'][@name='rPay']/following-sibling::span"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

OR Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='5'][@name='rPay']/following-sibling::span")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I hope it will help you :)

Please get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Comment: doesn't work either, doesn't click the button and isSelected() is still false

Comment: Did you check that manually without selenium that your application is responding as same. I ask this because if your application is not responding on IE in normal scenario then selenium can't help you.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try with same. try with second code